# memoir: different pagesizes

Tags: margins, memoir

I am using the `memoir` class and have my textblock set to a value so there are about 11 words on one line. This is great for the mainmatter of the report. But for some other pages (list of acronyms for example) it would be nicer if I could just use the full page width (or at least have smaller margins than in my main text). Same for my bibliography.

This way I would save some pages, and since it' s no real text that will be read, it doesn't matter if it has more than 11 words on one line.

Of course the textblock size etc are set in the preamble. Is there some way to use a larger/wider textblock on some pages? And if yes how?

Comment: It may well be possible to change the margins mid-document in `memoir`. However, have you considered to typeset the bibliography and the lists of acronyms in a somewhat smaller font size? (This is often done in professionally typeset books.)

Comment: I did, but even then im not completely satsified. I already tried that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to specify a page layout for the `mainmatter` and another page layout for the `backmatter`.

Since Release 5, `geometry` allows changing page layout mid-document by its command `\newgeometry` which you could call at the beginning of the `backmatter`.

According to the `memoir` manual, this class can be used together with `geometry`.

Comment: This was so easy, thx a lot!