# Is there a way to query the page size that I have set in the memoir class?

Tags: memoir, conditionals, geometry

In my preamble, I have:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}
```

I would like to later define some layout options based on the value of the page size, which in this case is `a5paper`.  I've looked a little at [pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/48816), and discovered that it can't be called before `\documentclass`, while [keyreader could be](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66643/48816), but maybe there's infact a `stock size` or `page size` value that I'm effectively setting while calling `memoir`, that I could use as a trigger for subsequent conditional actions.

Or maybe I should try defining a key *after* calling memoir, and then later [use the geometry package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12719/48816) to set the page size (and other things) accordingly?

Comment: @Jubobs, I've now implemented your first suggestion, using \@ifclasswith, and it's just what I need for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can (see [daleif's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170959/is-there-a-way-to-query-the-page-size-that-i-have-set-in-memoir-class/170965?noredirect=1#comment393977_170965)) use the LaTeX kernel macro called `\@ifclasswith` to test whether or not the `a5paper` option was passed to `memoir`, and do different things accordingly. One potential downside of this approach is that using `\@ifclasswith` is only allowed in the preamble, not in the body of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\makeatletter
\@ifclasswith{memoir}{a5paper}
{%
  % If the a5paper option was passed to memoir...
  % do something interesting; for instance:
  \AtBeginDocument{The pagesize is \texttt{a5paper}.\par}
}{%
  % Otherwise...
  % do something else.
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

### Alternative solution

According to the [`memoir` source code](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memoir.dtx), passing the `a5paper` class option merely triggers

```
\newcommand*{\stockav}{\stockheight=210mm \stockwidth=148mm}
```

Therefore, if an alternative approach is needed, you can perform tests on the values of `\stockheight` and `\stockwidth` instead.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

% test for a5paper
\ifdim\stockheight=210mm\relax
  \ifdim\stockwidth=148mm\relax
    % Put here what should only be applied only if the page size corresponds to A5 paper.
    % For instance...
    The pagesize is \texttt{a5paper}.\par
  \fi
\fi
\lipsum[1] % for filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Untested but can't you use ifclassloadedwith, or what ever it is called. There is a macro to test class or package options

Comment: @daleif You're right! That's a much simpler approach. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me what you're actually trying to do is write your own document class. So put the part of your current header that should be part of that class in `MyClass.cls` and make it look like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyClass}
\DeclareOption∗{\PassOptionsToClass\CurrentOption}{memoir}%
}
\LoadClass{memoir}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}{% do stuff
}
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{% do other stuff
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
% rest of your header goes here
```

Then your actual document just starts with

```
\documentclass{MyClass}
```

Comment: Hmmm... what if the OP already has many documents using the `memoir` class that he wants to refactor? Changing to `MyClass` might be tedious.

Comment: I only have one, and @Jubobs' `\@ifclasswith{memoir}{a5paper}` test was simple to implement.  For the moment, I'm only needing paper-size-based `geometry` settings, but if I need more, `MyClass` might be useful.

Comment: The most significant difference between the two approaches is that in the one case you're directly checking if a specific option was used while in the other you use an indirect test. Also, I was assuming that you in essence do want to implement your own document class in which case my solution would have been conceptually nicer. It is slightly more complicated though.